# ¿Cómo puedo darle seguimiento individual a objetos del mismo color y casi del mismo tamaño con openCV en java o python?

Tags: java, python, opencv, tracking

Necesito darle seguimiento a objetos del mismo color y casi del mismo tamaño con `openCV` de preferencia en `Java` escritorio o si no en `Python`.

Estoy trabajando con una matriz de enteros

```java
int[1000][1000]
```

Ya tengo aplicado el seguimiento y el Filtro Kalman en el lenguaje `Python`, pero lo que hago es guardar la matriz como imagen desde `Java` y la leo y dibujo los contornos de los blancos con `Python`, no me interesan tanto los contornos, sino separar  los blancos individualmente y darle el seguimiento. Algo así como ponerlos en una lista y mostrar su posición original y la siguiente posición posible calculado por el Kalman.

El problema resalta que en `Java` no he podido realizar el Filtro Kalman y también que la lista de los blancos creo que los entrega siempre al azar, habrá alguna forma de identificar cada blanco por un `id` o algo así para poder mostrarlos en una lista? Y si saben la equivalencia del código que tengo de `Python` en `Java` se los agradecería...

Anexo el código que tengo en `Python` en donde le doy seguimiento a objetos de color azul y tamaño mayor a 1000p mediante grabación de la cámara:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import sys
import time


# Instanciando OCV Filtro Kalman
class KalmanFilter:

    kf = cv.KalmanFilter(4, 2)
    kf.measurementMatrix = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]], np.float32)
    kf.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

    # Esta función estima la siguiente posición del objeto
    def Estimate(self, coordX, coordY):
        measured = np.array([[np.float32(coordX)], [np.float32(coordY)]])
        self.kf.correct(measured)
        predicted = self.kf.predict()
        return predicted



# Seguimiento de objetos de color azul
class ProcessImage:

    def DetectObject(self):

        vid = cv.VideoCapture(0)

        width = int(vid.get(3))
        height = int(vid.get(4))

        # Objeto del Filtro Kalman
        kfObj = KalmanFilter()
        predictedCoords = np.zeros((2, 1), np.float32)

        while True:
            rc, frame = vid.read()

            if(rc == True):

                frameHSV = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                mask = cv.inRange(frameHSV, np.array([100,100,20], np.uint8), np.array([125,255,255], np.uint8))

                contornos,_ = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

                for c in contornos :
                    area = cv.contourArea(c)
                    if area >= 1000:

                        M = cv.moments(c)
                        if (M["m00"]==0) : M["m00"] = 1
                        x = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
                        y = int(M["m01"]/M["m00"])

                        predictedCoords = kfObj.Estimate(x, y)

                        cv.circle(frame, (x, y), 7, (0, 255, 0), -1)
                        font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
                        cv.putText(frame,'{},{}'.format(x, y), (x+10, y), font, 0.75, (0, 255, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)
                        nuevoContorno = cv.convexHull(c)
                        cv.drawContours(frame, [nuevoContorno], 0, (255, 0, 0), 3)

                        # Salida de posición actual después de la segmentación
                        cv.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), 20, [255,255,255], 2, 8)
                        cv.line(frame,(int(x), int(y + 20)), (int(x + 50), int(y + 20)), [255,255,255], 2,8)
                        cv.putText(frame, "Actual", (int(x + 50), int(y + 20)), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, [255,255,255])

                        # Salida de resultado Filtro Kalman
                        cv.circle(frame, (predictedCoords[0], predictedCoords[1]), 10, [0,255,255], 2, 8)
                        cv.line(frame, (predictedCoords[0] + 16, predictedCoords[1] - 15), (predictedCoords[0] + 50, predictedCoords[1] - 30), [0, 255, 255], 2, 8)
                        cv.putText(frame, "Siguiente", (int(predictedCoords[0] + 50), int(predictedCoords[1] - 30)), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, [0, 255, 255])


                cv.imshow('Input', frame)

                #time.sleep(2)

                if (cv.waitKey(300) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
                    break

            else:
                break

        vid.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()


# Función Principal
def main():
    processImg = ProcessImage()
    processImg.DetectObject()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

print('Program Completed!')
```

El código aún no está terminado ya que si solo detecta un objeto funciona bien, pero si son varios objetos el Kalman ya no funciona, necesito guardar cada objeto detectado como una instancia y aplicarle el Kalman individualmente pero para eso necesito diferenciar los blancos de manera individual...

Les agradezco su ayuda anticipadamente!!!